# Почему функция не видит recyclerView в фрагменте при ее вызове из другой активити?

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-view

У меня есть фрагмент в составе которого есть recyclerView. В функции `onCreateView` я этот виджет обьявляю и дальше вызываю функцию в которой заполняю адаптер и прикрепляю его к виджету. Вроде все нормально и список грузится прекрасно. Все отображается. Этот фрагмент находится в `frameLayout` в `navigationView` в котором так же есть тулбар с кнопками. Я пытаюсь при нажатии кнопки на тулбаре вызвать эту функцию в фрагменте. Но у меня выскакивает ошибка о том что мой виджет null. Я пробовал сделать глобальную переменную view и инициализировать виджет непосредственно из функции, но это не сработало. Пробовал перекинуть в синглтон и оттуда грузить данные, но это тоже не решило проблему. Задача данной функции состоит в том чтобы слать запрос на сервер и полученные данные отображать в списке. При первом запуске фрагменте все нормально, а дальше вероятнее всего я миную инициализацию списка и иду сразу к его заполнению. Вот как все выглядит в фрагменте:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_job_list, container, 
       false);
...
recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.job_list);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


        getL_jobs(offset, type, sp.getString("access_token", ""));
        return rootView;
}
```

и вот функция:

```
public void getL_jobs(final int offset, final int type, String a_token) {
MySingleton.getInstance().apiService().get_list("Bearer " + a_token, type, offset).enqueue(new Callback<Jobs>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Jobs> call, @NonNull Response<Jobs> response) {
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
count = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getCount();
if (count > 0) {
jobModelArrayList = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getJobs();
j_adapter = new JobAdapter(jobModelArrayList, getContext());
j_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
recyclerView.setAdapter(j_adapter);
}
}
....
}
```

не могу понять как решить эту проблему. Суть вообще в том чтобы вызывать эту функцию и менять при этом значение offset чтобы можно прогружать список вакансий дальше.

вот ошибка:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.developer_4.test_login, PID: 11918
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.developer_4.test_login.JobAGENT.JobList$1.onResponse(JobList.java:115)
```

вот строка на которую указывает ошибка в функции получения и заполнения списка:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(j_adapter);
```

Comment: Видимо, в том месте, где вы вызываете фрагмент, его нет и он `null`. Без кода этой части и стэктрейса ошибки что-то больше сказать сложно.

Comment: @Jarvis_J, обновил вопрос, этой информации достаточно или еще что-то упустил?

Comment: Скорее всего вы вызываете метод до того как фрагмент "прогрузился"  и стал видимым - в этот момент ваш RV = null (то, что я увидел из приведенного кода). Как вариант - исполнять это код с задержкой через `Handler` или вызывать его только если "`view` фрагмента точно прогрузилось" и не null

Comment: я приблизительно понял что вы имеете в виду, но все-таки не очень понимаю две вещи - задержка выполнения, это круто, но ее куда вставить, там где я вызываю эту функцию из navigationDrawer? и второй непонятный момент - второй вариант решения проблемы - как понять что view фрагмента прогрузилось, чисто гипотетически можно сделать то что вы предлагаете в втором варианте но не очень понятно как именно.

Comment: Один из вариантов - отправлять из `onCreateView` фрагмента колбэк "я прогрузился!". По задержке, да, там где вызываете всю функцию. Это скорее костыль, т.к. на разных устройствах будет разное время прогрузки. Но попробуйте задержку 500мс, должно хватить. Единственное - не знаю как это скажется на UX)

Comment: но я так понял для текущей проблемы лучше использовать колбэк, он будет более адекватный для всех устройств. Я просто думал как можно вызвать onCreateView, но так и не понял как это сделать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87788/discussion-between-jarvis-j-and-andrew-goroshko).